# Angular: Function not running after page load

Tags: angularjs

I have a webpage that runs well, but on a certain route, it would not load certain functions. For example, this is code:

```
myApp.controller('people', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
        console.log('la 1');

        $scope.allPeople = function() {
            // This does not run when refreshed at https://www.website.com/people
            console.log('la 2');
        }
    })
]);
```

This has the same behavior, `la 1` works, not `la 2`:

```
myApp.controller('people', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log('la 1');
    $scope.allPeople = function() {
        console.log('la 2');
    }
}]);
```

These are routes:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../../templates/all.html',
        controller: 'all'
    })
    .when('/people', {
        templateUrl: '../../templates/people.html',
        controller: 'people'
    })
});
```

When I load `https://www.website.com`, and navigate to `People` tab, it loads list of people. But, when I load the page WHILE in the `People` tab, the page would load, but without the list: I see `la 1` printed, not `la 2`.

How can I run the `allPeople` when refreshed from `/people`?

Comment: what route module are you using ?
show us how you set up the routes.

Comment: @eranotzap, done

Comment: ok nothing call allPeople function you only declare it.

Comment: @eranotzap, how can I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you only declared the function but never execute it.

```
myApp.controller('people', ['$scope', function($scope) {

     $scope.allPeople = function() {          
          console.log('la 2');
     }

     $scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
         console.log('la 1');        
         $scope.allPeople();
     });   
]);
```

Additionally don't declare it every time you route.
And don't forget to unregister the watch (thanks @NainishModi).

```
   myApp.controller('people', ['$scope', function($scope) {

     $scope.allPeople = $scope.allPeople || function() {          
          console.log('la 2');
     }

     var deReg = $scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
         console.log('la 1');        
         $scope.allPeople();
     })

      //deRegister watch
      $scope.$on('$destroy', deReg);
]);
```